# Order a list of objects by value match in another list

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have two (almost always) equal lists made of different type of objects but with some common properties (and always unique values):

```
List<Object1> list1 = new List<Object1>();
List<Object2> list2 = new List<Object2>();
```

Then I need to order the `list2` based on the order of matches by a property with `list1`.

Example:

```
list1:

0, "FMS", prop2, prop3; 
1, "KFF", prop2, prop3; 
2, "FOA", prop2, prop3;
3, "RDA", prop2, prop3;
4, "KFP", prop2, prop3; 

list2:

Before:
991, prop1, "RDA", prop2, prop3, etc; 
992, prop1, "FMS", prop3, prop4, etc;
993, prop1, "KFF", prop3, prop4, etc;
994, prop1, "KFP", prop3, prop4, etc;
995, prop1, "FOA", prop3, prop4, etc;

After:
992, prop1, "FMS", prop3, prop4, etc;
993, prop1, "KFF", prop3, prop4, etc;
995, prop1, "FOA", prop3, prop4, etc;
991, prop1, "RDA", prop3, prop4, etc;
994, prop1, "KFP", prop3, prop4, etc;
```

I need something like

```
list2.OrderBy(x => Where(list1.prop1 == list2.prop2))
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
list2.OrderBy(x => list1.FindIndex(y => y.prop1 == x.prop2));
```

Note that if no item is found that's matching the predicate, you will get -1 back, so all these items will be piled up at the top (of course, you can write code to ignore them completely, or pile them down at the bottom, or whatever.